# Laravel show data 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
flights(id, title, number)
stations(id, title)
flight_price(id, price, flight_id, stationA_id, stationB_id)
flight_station(flight_id, station_id)
```

`flight_station` is a pivot table.

My models:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    public function stations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Station', 'flight_station', 'flight_id', 'station_id')
    }

    // To attach data
    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\FlightPrice', 'flight_price', 'flight_id', 'stationA_id')
            ->withPivot('price');
    }

    public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\FlightPrice', 'flight_id');
    }
}

// Station
class Station extends Model
{
    public function flights()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Flight', 'flight_station', 'station_id', 'flight_id');
    }


}

class FlightPrice extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'flight_price';

    public function flights()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Flight', 'flight_price');
    }
}
```

I need the next result (find by id flight):

```
|stationA_id|stationA_title||stationB_id|stationB_title|price|
```

Comment: What you "need" is really unclear. Please describe more precisely the expected result. Can you provide some of the work you've done so far?

Comment: How to get the data and display it. How to link all use eloquent-relationships ?

Comment: There is a really good [series of free videos to start with Laravel on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017)

Comment: Get what data? Have you looked at the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: If I do this like this: 
$flight = Flight::with('price', 'stations')->find($id);
foreach($flight->price as $value) - i dont get data station title.

Comment: You should add this to your question so we know what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are trying to retrieve a flight like this:

```php
$flight = Flight::with(['price', 'stations'])->find($id);
```

This returns a `Flight` model *with* the `Price` and `Station` models because [you eager loaded the relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Now `$flight->price` will return the `Price` model associated with the `Flight` model. If it is not a collection - which I believe is true - the `foreach` loop has little meaning (or at least not the one you expect). In fact it will loop through the public attributes of the `Model` class (`incrementing`, `exists`, `wasRecentlyCreated` and `timestamps`).

So the following piece of code will return 4 booleans.

```php
foreach ($flight->price as $value) {
    dump($value);
}
```

If you want to return the station identifiers, the station titles and the price for each flight then maybe try something like this:

```php
foreach ($flight->stations as $station) {
    dump($station->id);
    dump($station->title);
}

// I assume the Price model has an attribute named value
dump($flight->price->value)
```